# different php versions causing problems

Tags: php

Can anyone spot anything that would be causing me massive problems between the following two server/php configs:

http://www.turkishrealestateforsale.com/phpinfo.php
and
http://rent-turkey-property.com/phpinfo.php

I am having particular problems with form processing, including one where it seems to stop processing half way through the script for no apparent reason, echo works here, but not here.

I am guessing it is the Server API being Apache 2.0 Handler and CGI, if this is right, can anyone point me to a cheat sheet or any documentation on the Idiosyncrasies between the two.

Comment: Probably some error stopping - do you have error reporting enabled? It's hard to look for errors so blindly...

Comment: sounds like the program is breaking but not reporting the error to screen. you've probably got error reporting switched off, but you should still be able to see the errors if you check your server error logs.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display_errors setting is set to OFF, try STOUT instead and see if it helps find those errors.

Comment: well spotted, I have never come across a set up with this off so it never occurred to me.